# Active Directory Azure - Password WriteBack

Tags: active-directory, entra-id, write-back

I have a small and maybe silly question in regards to Azure AD, when the password is changed in Azure using for example SSPR, how long does it takes to writeBack the password to AD, considering that the password writeback function is enabled. Is this instant or it has some dependencies ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the appropriate license? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-writeback

Comment: The license is not a problem, is not a matter of service disruption here, I was demanded by the customer to provide proof that the writeback password is done instantly before going with this solution, the only reference I had is the same link you provided which for me makes sense but not enough for some ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Zero-delay feedback: **Password writeback is a synchronous operation**. Your users are **notified immediately** if their password did not meet the policy or could not be reset or changed for any reason.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-writeback

So there is no delay. If you want proof, you should be able to see it in the Synchronization Service Manager UI on your Azure AD Connect server.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-service-manager-ui

Change your password and monitor the sync. Should be instantaneous.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you !